# Ruby on rails radio_button_tag broke with onclick fucntion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a radio button with onclick function so when the user change status from open to close promp and alert message and asking for a reason, we have it on html + javascript and working fine so when we try to make it rails way, we put as default value open **:checked => true** so when we put the **onclick: "comfirm();"** rails ignore **   <%= radio_button_tag(:status, "Open", :checked => true) %>
** and put as checked the Close

```
   <%= radio_button_tag(:status, "Open", :checked => true) %>
   <%= label_tag(:status_ticket, "Open", id: "open") %>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:status, "Close") %>
   <%= label_tag(:status_ticket, "Close", id: "close") %>
```

[image: output]

but when i want to add the on click function broke the thing

ignore the :checked => true and set as checked the close

like so

```
   <%= radio_button_tag(:status, "Open", :checked => true) %>
   <%= label_tag(:status_ticket, "Open", id: "open") %>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:status, "Close", onclick: "comfirm();") %>
   <%= label_tag(:status_ticket, "Close", id: "close") %>
```

[image: output2]

i don't think the function broke the things becouse is realy simple as you can see bellow

```
function comfirm() {
  var result = prompt('Why do you want to close the ticket?: ');
  document.getElementById("reason").value = result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter for `radio_button_tag` allows to indicate [if the radio is checked](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag), so `onclick: "comfirm();"` is interpreted as `true`. To make it work, you should add it as a fourth parameter:

```
radio_button_tag(:status, "Close", false, onclick: "comfirm();")
```